# How to output "No product dimension" in csv for products that haven't got dimensions display on the page?(python,web scraping)

Tags: python, web-scraping

I made a web scraping program with python and I would like to display "No product dimension" in the column "Product dimensions". These products don't have dimensions display on Amazon. The code that should be replaced is on the try catch block with the dimension. I attached the program. I will appreciate any help.

THIS IS THE OUTPUT OF THIS PROGRAM! I WOULD LIKE TO REPLACE THE ASINS FROM THE PRODUCT DIMENSIONS COLUMN WITH NO PRODUCT DIMENSION.

[image]

```html
from selenium import webdriver
import csv
import io

proxies = {
    'http': 'http://5.189.133.231:80',
    'https': 'https://27.111.43.178:8080'
}

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server="%s"' % ';'.join(['%s=%s' % (k, v) for k, v in proxies.items()]))

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\Andrei-PC\Downloads\webdriver\chromedriver.exe",
                          chrome_options=chrome_options)
header = ['Product title', 'ASIN', 'Product Weight', 'Product dimensions', 'URL']

with open('csv/products.csv', "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    writer.writerow(header)

links = [
   'https://www.amazon.com/Fermtech-regular-Auto-Siphon-Tubing/dp/B06XMR433X/ref=sr_1_2?s=kitchen&ie=UTF8&qid=1520274561&sr=1-2&keywords=-hhhg',
    'https://www.amazon.com/Hydro-Flask-Wide-Mouth-Flip/dp/B01ACATW7E/ref=sr_1_3?s=kitchen&ie=UTF8&qid=1520348607&sr=1-3&keywords=-gfds',
    'https://www.amazon.com/Cosmetics-Organizer-Compartments-Christmas-birthday/dp/B01BXDDU04/ref=sr_1_4569/138-3260504-2979110?s=bedbath&ie=UTF8&qid=1520585778&sr=1-4569&keywords=-sdfg'
]

for i in range(len(links)):

    driver.get(links[i])

    product_title = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="productTitle"][1]')
    prod_title = [x.text for x in product_title]

    try:
        asin = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//div[@class ="pdTab"]/table/tbody/tr/td)[24]').text
    except:
        print('no ASIN template one')

    try:
        weight = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//div[@class ="pdTab"]/table/tbody/tr/td)[2]').text
    except:
        print('no weight template one')

    try:
        dimension = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//div[@class ="pdTab"]/table/tbody/tr/td)[4]').text
    except:
        print('no dimension template one')

    try:
        asin = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//table[@id="productDetailsTable"]/tbody/tr/td/div/ul/li)[3]').text
    except:
        print('no ASIN template two')

    try:
        weight = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//table[@id="productDetailsTable"]/tbody/tr/td/div/ul/li)[3]').text
    except:
        print('no weight template two')
        
    try:
        dimension = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//table[@id="productDetailsTable"]/tbody/tr/td/div/ul/li)[3]').text
    except:
        print('no dimension template two')

    try:
        asin = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[contains(b, "ASIN:")]').text
    except:
        print('no ASIN template three')

    try:
        weight = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[contains(b, "Shipping Weight:")]').text
    except:
        print('no weight template three')

    try:
        dimension = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[contains(b, "Product Dimensions: ")]').text
    except:
        print('no dimension template three')

    try:
        data = [prod_title[0], asin, weight, dimension, links[i]]
    except:
        print('no data')

    with io.open('csv/products.csv', "a", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as output:
        writer = csv.writer(output)
        writer.writerow(data)
```

Comment: I see you have 3 different templates to extract the required information. I am assuming that on a particular page, either of the 3 templates would work, and I guess every product has **ASIN**. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, every product has ASIN you can see on the Product details section of the page. But they don't have Product dimension and I would like to replace the actual information that you can see in the csv table that I've attached with No product dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-arrange your code such that if it finds ASIN in any of the template, it doesnt check for the other templates, since any web-page would follow either of the 3 templates.

jbtw, Your 4th, 5th and 6th try statements have the same code to extract 3 different variables. You need to fix that.

So back to your question, just set dimension to your required string in the except block (i.e. in case it doesnt find a dimension).

```
try:
    dimension = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[contains(b, "Product Dimensions: ")]').text
except:
    dimension = 'NO PRODUCT DIMENSION'
```

Here is the re-arranged version of the code, (not tested), but I am sure it would work.

```
for i in range(len(links)):
    asinFound = False
    driver.get(links[i])

    product_title = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="productTitle"][1]')
    prod_title = [x.text for x in product_title]
    if asinFound == False: #try template one
        try:
            asin = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//div[@class ="pdTab"]/table/tbody/tr/td)[24]').text
            asinFound = True #dont need to try other templates
        except:
            print('no ASIN template one')

        try:
            weight = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//div[@class ="pdTab"]/table/tbody/tr/td)[2]').text
        except:
            print('no weight template one')

        try:
            dimension = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//div[@class ="pdTab"]/table/tbody/tr/td)[4]').text
        except:
            dimension = 'No Product Dimension'
            print('no dimension template one')

    if asinFound == False: #try template two
        try:
            asin = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//table[@id="productDetailsTable"]/tbody/tr/td/div/ul/li)[3]').text
            asinFound = True #dont need to try other templates
        except:
            print('no ASIN template two')

        try:
            weight = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//table[@id="productDetailsTable"]/tbody/tr/td/div/ul/li)[3]').text
        except:
            print('no weight template two')

        try:
            dimension = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//table[@id="productDetailsTable"]/tbody/tr/td/div/ul/li)[3]').text
        except:
            dimension = 'No Product Dimension'
            print('no dimension template two')
    if asinFound == False: #try template three
        try:
            asin = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[contains(b, "ASIN:")]').text
        except:
            print('no ASIN template three')

        try:
            weight = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[contains(b, "Shipping Weight:")]').text
        except:
            print('no weight template three')

        try:
            dimension = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[contains(b, "Product Dimensions: ")]').text
        except:
            dimension = 'No Product Dimension'
            print('no dimension template three')

    try:
        data = [prod_title[0], asin, weight, dimension, links[i]]
    except:
        print('no data')

    with io.open('csv/products.csv', "a", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as output:
        writer = csv.writer(output)
        writer.writerow(data)
```

Comment: Thank you! I understand now.